# Additional labels on x-axis as legend of a seperator

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm new here, so plz if I forgot sth, forgive me.
I'm trying to get sth like the image below. But I'm struggling in two points: my lines don't start directly from the y-axis and I want below the measurement of the x-axis and the label of the x-axis two labels as legend to the vline. I tried to get it with annotation_custom, but this placed it in the plot itself, but I want it on the x-axis or at the top of the plot without being written on the graph itself.

So far I used the following code:

```
require(reshape)
library(ggplot2)

user <- gl(3, 1)
Meas1 <- c(0.7, 0.3, 0.3)
Meas2 <- c(0.7, 0.3, 0.3)
Meas3 <- c(0.2, 0.4, 0.4)
group <- c(3, 2, 2)
df <- data.frame(user=user, Meas1=Meas1, Meas2=Meas2, Meas3=Meas3, group=group)

dfm <- melt(df, id.vars=c("user", "group"))
flevels=as.vector.factor(unique(dfm$variable))

ggplot(dfm, aes(x=factor(variable), y=value, colour=user, group=user)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  scale_x_discrete(breaks=flevels, labels=flevels)
```

This is how i would like to have it (the labels are class1 and class2)

[image]

I would really appriciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

To start the lines directly at the y-axis you need to put the expand paramater to the scale_x_discrete function, like:

```
scale_x_discrete(breaks=flevels, labels=flevels, expand = c(0,0))
```

You can add a legend like:

```
theme(legend.position = 'bottom')
```

The result will be three labels as long as you have three users at your data with the same values. I think subsetting your data by eliminating user 2 will be the most easiest way to get two labels.

Comment: Thank you advek, that already helped a lot. I didn't know that. Do you also have an idea how to get the labels to the separator

Comment: I edit my original answer, hopefully this is what you are looking for.

Comment: I don't wanna shift my legend. It's like in the picture of my question. There are two labels between the x-axis labels (Meas1, Meas2, Meas3) and the x-label (factor(variable)). I want this like this, so that you know at the left side of the vline you have class1 and at the right side class2

Comment: Ah, I didn't saw the picture! I'm sorry. Maybe you can add a variable to your data so you can split the graph with the facet_grid() function. I need to go for now, maybe I can try to fix it later today. GL

Answer (score 0):

Some possibilities spring to mind. I present three below. In all three, I position the "Class 1" and "Class 2" labels at the top of the chart. But I'm not sure how or where you want to position the demarcation between "Class 1" and "Class 2". I positioned it a little more than half way across the chart.

The first is the simplest. It positions the labels using `annotate`. As far as I know, there is no easy way to get a short line segment to demarcate the two regions. Here, I draw a line across the chart, but because it traverses the plot panel, I think it is a distraction.

The second constructs a grob containing the two labels and a short line segment, then positions the grob using `annotation_custom`. The third also constructs a grob (although the grob construction is a little simpler), then positions the grob using functions from the `gtable` package.

More comments below.

```
# Your data
require(reshape)

user <- gl(3, 1)
Meas1 <- c(0.7, 0.3, 0.3)
Meas2 <- c(0.7, 0.3, 0.3)
Meas3 <- c(0.2, 0.4, 0.4)
group <- c(3, 2, 2)
df <- data.frame(user=user, Meas1=Meas1, Meas2=Meas2, Meas3=Meas3, group=group)

dfm <- melt(df, id.vars = c("user", "group"))
flevels = as.vector.factor(unique(dfm$variable))
```

**First method**: `annotate`

The labels are positioned at the top of the plot panel, then uses `vjust` to move the text outside the plot panel. The top plot margin is widened to give space for the labels. Because text is being plotted outside the plot panel, clipping to the plot panel needs to be turned off.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)

# The plot
p = ggplot(dfm, aes(x = factor(variable), y = value, colour = user, group = user)) + 
   geom_line() + 
   scale_x_discrete(breaks = flevels, labels = flevels) +
   theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1.5, .1, .1, .1), "lines"))

# plus the annotations
p = p + annotate("text", x = c(1.35, 2.85), y = Inf, label = c("Class 1", "Class 2"), vjust = -.75) +
        annotate("segment", x = 2.2, xend = 2.2, y = -Inf, yend = Inf)

# Turn off clipping
gp = ggplotGrob(p)
gp$layout[gp$layout$name == "panel", "clip"] = "off"

# Draw the plot
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(gp)
```

**Second method**: `annotation_custom`

There's a couple of ways to position the elements. Here I do the positioning in the construction of the grob, then the `annotation_custom` can span for `-Inf` to `Inf`.  There was a little bit of trial-and-error to get the y coordinates right. Also, because the grob is being plotted outside the plot panel, the top plot margin needs to be widened, and clipping to the panel needs to be turned off.

```
xpos = .6 # of the demarcation between the two labels; in npc units

# Construct the grob
lab1 = textGrob("Class 1", x = .5 * xpos, y = 1.02)
lab2 = textGrob("Class 2", x = .5 + .5 * xpos, y = 1.02)
seg = linesGrob(x = c(xpos, xpos), y = c(1, 1.04))

labs = gTree(children = gList(lab1, lab2, seg))

p = ggplot(dfm, aes(x = factor(variable), y = value, colour = user, group = user)) + 
   geom_line() + 
   scale_x_discrete(breaks = flevels, labels = flevels) +
   theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1.5, .1, .1, .1), "lines")) +

   annotation_custom(labs, xmin = -Inf, xmax = Inf, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf)

gp = ggplotGrob(p)
gp$layout[gp$layout$name == "panel", "clip"] = "off"

grid.newpage()
grid.draw(gp)
```

**Third method**: `gtable` functions

The grob is constructed, but there is need to worry about y coordinates. The `gtable` functions add a row to the top of the gtable (i.e., the plot), then insert the grob into that row. `t` and `l` refer to rows and columns in the gtable layout. `gtable_show_layout(gp)` will show the layout. Also see gtable help pages (`?gtable_add_rows` and `?gtable_add_grob`)

```
library(gtable)

xpos = .6 # in npc units
lab1 = textGrob("Class 1", x = .5 * xpos)
lab2 = textGrob("Class 2", x = .5 + .5 * xpos)
seg = linesGrob(x = c(xpos, xpos))

labs = gTree(children = gList(lab1, lab2, seg))

p = ggplot(dfm, aes(x = factor(variable), y = value, colour = user, group = user)) + 
   geom_line() + 
   scale_x_discrete(breaks = flevels, labels = flevels)

gp = ggplotGrob(p)

row = 2
gp = gtable_add_rows(gp, unit(2, "grobheight", lab1), row)

l = gp$layout[grepl("panel", gp$layout$name), ]$l
gp = gtable_add_grob(gp, labs, t = row + 1, l = l)

grid.newpage()
grid.draw(gp)
```

[image]